# Building a plugin architecture

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a simple plugin architecture that allows for a nice simple API in use. Consider the following code:

```
//the core library namespace
var testObj = {};

//constuctor
testObj = function() {

};

//The plugin
testObj.prototype.test = (function(){

    var i = 0;

    var init = function() {
        alert('initialized');
    }

    return {
        init: init,

        render: function(){
            return i;
        }
};

}());


var p = new testObj();
//p.test.init();
p.test();
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8LwRL/

I want users to be able to call the init method by doing p.test(). Currently this doesn't work and anyone using the plugin would have to call p.test.init(). Is there any way that I can abstract that away so the user can call the prototype method by name and have the init run automatically?

Comment: `p.test.init()` wouldn't work either. I assume you mean `p.test().init()`. *"have the init run automatically"*: just call `init` inside `test` before you return the object?

Comment: I don't think so no. test is a method of testObj. This works: http://jsfiddle.net/8LwRL/

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that it is an IIFE. That makes the whole comment obsolete. If you want to make `p.test` callable, then you have to return a function, not an object. Inside that function you could then call `init`.

Comment: Unrelated side note: `var testObj = {}` is unnecessary because you're immediately overwriting it with a function the next line.

Comment: I know but for clarity's sake

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more about what your goals are for both `init` and `render`? I'm only guessing `init` sets up the test and `render` runs it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already mentioned in my comment, if you want to make `p.test` callable, you have to return a function from the IIFE, not a (simple) object. The most straightforward approach would be to return `init` itself. Your code could then look like

```
testObj.prototype.test = (function(){
    var i = 0;
    var init = function() {
        alert('initialized');
    };

    init.render = function(){
        return i;
    };
    return init;
}());
```

It appears a bit odd (to me) but it would do what you want.

Comment: Yes tried that...but that code only works if I call p.test.init() http://jsfiddle.net/8LwRL/3/. I was trying to work out a way to be able to call just p.test() and have the init called automatically

Comment: @Mike: It does exactly what you described (http://jsfiddle.net/8LwRL/4/). If it doesn't work for you then you didn't explain your problem properly. *"I was trying to work out a way to be able to call just p.test() and have the init called automatically"* That's what my answer describes. Did you read it thoroughly?

Comment: Apologies I tested the incorrect block of code. Your solution does exactyl what I asked for. Thanks

Comment: I've implemented an alternative approach here via an extend method...wondering if this could be a cleaner approach? http://jsfiddle.net/Xv7mA/1

Answer (score 1):

My corrected version:

```
//constuctor
var testObj = function(options) {
this.init(options);
};

//I prefer to use jQuery.extend() to extend prototype. Its look better
$.extend(testObj.prototype,{
    options: {},
    init: function (options) {
       this.options = options;
       console.log('Name on init ' + options.name );
       this.options.name = 'Peter';
    },
    test: function () {
        console.log('name on test: ' + this.options.name);
    }
})


var p = new testObj({name: 'John'});
p.test();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8LwRL/7/)

Comment: `init` is not actually a method of the object created by the constructor. `this.test.init()` should work though.

Comment: @Vitalii, this is food for thought. Perhaps I will implement my own extend functionality...